# IFrameElement downloads HTML instead of Display, why?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, gwt

In my GWT code I am adding an Iframeelement inside HTMl panel. I am using iframe.src attribute, I validated the HTML file path it is valid. But instead of displaying HTML content file get downloaded but is never shown in iframe.

```
 HTMLPanel mainPanel;
 final IFrameElement myIframe = Document.get().createIFrameElement();

@Override
public void loadFrame( String htmlFile )
{
 myIframe.setSrc( htmlFile ); 
 mainPanel.getElement().appendChild(myIframe);
}
```

Can somebody guide, what I am doing wrong that iframe downloads html but doesn't dsiplays